# Can I reduce the space chaindata takes up?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync, memory

So the size of my chaindata folder has snowballed to close to 80GB. Is there a way to reduce it or is the only way to delete it and resync geth with --syncmode fast?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do the `--fast` mode to reduce the chain data size. And yes, you can delete the old chaindata.

Comment: Will that prune existing data or are you suggesting deleting and resyncing?

Comment: Exactly, when I try running it with --fast, I get a warning "Blockchain not empty, fast sync disabled"

Comment: That was my worry. My internet is super slow right now so didn't want to have to re-sync it, even with --fast mode. Oh well, I'll do it later :)